# JavaScript confirm from C# codebehind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I use following code-behind for javascript pop up for conforming, it works well but it does redirect the user to TestPage.aspx always regardless of user selection whether Yes or No.

```
lblMsg.InnerHtml = @"
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        confirm('Do you want to continue?');
        window.location='TestPage.aspx?ID=" + Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString() + "&txtTest=" + Server.UrlEncode(txtTest.Text) + strSomeString + "'
    </script>";
```

Any idea?

And I use this, this time there is no pop up even.

```
lblMsg.InnerHtml = @"
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        confirm('Do you want to continue?');
        window.location='TestPage.aspx?ID=" + Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString() + "&txtTest=" + Server.UrlEncode(txtTest.Text) + strSomeString + "'; return false;
    </script>";
```

Comment: Is it *incorrect* to format the code with line-breaks at the `;`? It would help me with the code. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try:

```
lblMsg.InnerHtml = @"
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        if(confirm('Do you want to continue?')) {
            window.location='TestPage.aspx?ID=" + Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString() + "&txtTest=" + Server.UrlEncode(txtTest.Text) + strSomeString + "'; 
        }
    </script>";
```

The `confirm` function returns a bool depending on whether or not the user confirmed the choice.  You can use that to redirect to the next page only if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the returned answer from confirm dialog. And depending on that do what you want. you need to edit your javascript like this,

```
var answer = confirm("Do you want to continue?")
   if (answer){
            window.location='TestPage.aspx?ID="' + Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString() +  "&txtTest=" + Server.UrlEncode(txtTest.Text) + strSomeString + "\""; 
    return false;
   }
```

Comment: This format is definitely much easier to understand. Although, from a C# point of view, the bool if-block semantics seem a bit odd. But that's OT ...I digress...

Comment: ...or maybe it's the `return false;` that is bugging me. Why is that needed? Just asking because it seems out of place and useless ...???